# Can maths functions "return" multiple different mathematical objects?

Tags: functions, computer-science, type-theory

In computer science, there are statically and dynamically typed languages, with statically typed languages generally being stricter about types of variables, function parameters, etc. To what extent can maths be considered "statically typed" (obviously this isn't the correct term but hopefully you understand what I'm asking) and how strict is it?

For example, do mathematical functions always have to return the same mathematical object (e.g. number, vector, etc.), or can the "type" (to use a computer science term) vary depending on the arguments it receives? I was wondering whether something like this makes any sense:
$$
    f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    x + 2& \text{if } x > 1\\
    [1, 2, 3]              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$ i.e. $f(x)$ can return a number or a vector.

Comment: Functions always return elements of a given set. You decide what kind of objects are inside that set to pick from. If you want them to be objects of varying type, you're free to do so, if you think it's convenient.

Comment: We then write $f:\Bbb N\to(\Bbb N\cup\bigcup_n\Bbb N^n)$ to indicate the codomain, and then we can use the same formula for the assignment.

Comment: Squaring applies to both numbers anf matrices

Comment: Function overloading occurs in mathematics, for example $\exp()$ denotes the exponential function from ${\mathbb R}$ to ${\mathbb R}$ but it also denotes the exponential of complex numbers or the exponential in a Lie algebra. They are seen as three different functions however.

Comment: Under the standard, set-theoretic definition, a function is just a set of ordered pairs (a,b) such that if (a,b) and (a,c) are in the set then b=c. In the category of sets and functions, functions come with a specific codomain, which other comments are talking about, but you don't really need it. Your function is a set of ordered pairs satisfying the condition *if*, you specify the domain. Is your function defined on reals, complex numbers, polygons? There are type-theoretic foundations of mathematics, but they're nowhere near as popular, and I don't know much about them.

Comment: Note that you aren't actually returning multiple objects, that would be like f(0)=1 and 2 and 3, i.e. (0,1), (0,2) and (0,3) are all in your set, which is of course not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f: A \to B$ maps elements of a domain set $A$ to elements of a domain set $B$.

As a set can be any collection of objects, it doesn't actually make sense to talk of objects being different "types".

Consider the $B = \{2, \pi, [1,3,7], fish, Sherlock\ Holmes, invisible\ green\ thoughts\}$.

$2$ is a natural number, $\pi$ is a transcendental irrational real number, $[1,3,7]$ is a vector, $fish$ is a group of animals, $Sherlock\ Holmes$ is a fictional character, $invisible\ green\ thoughts$ is a hypothetical idea of Noam Chomsky.  Are these the same type of object?

The answer is a emphatic:  YES!  The are all objects of the type-- Belonging to set $B$.

And $f: \mathbb N \to B$ via $$f(n) = \begin{cases} 2&\text{if }n\text{ is prime}\\\pi&\text{if }n\text{ is even composite}\\ [1,3,7]&\text{if }n\text{ is an odd perfect square}\\Sherlock\ Holmes&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ is a perfectly valid (non-surjective) function that does what a good function should; it maps every element of a specific set ($\mathbb N$) to a distinct element of a specific set ($B$).

Answer (score 0):

> can the "type" (to use a computer science term) vary depending on the arguments it receives

That is typically what a dependent type theory allows, with [dependent product types](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dependent+product+type) and many other constructions.

That does however not mean that a dependent type cannot be verified "statically": in a constructive type theory, type checking is usually decidable.